# why won't apk file update

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I'm developing an android app using Eclipse.  I export the app using the Export Android App function.  I sign and align the resulting apk file.  I then copy this apk to a webserver and try to install it on my phone.  It goes though the installation steps, and when I test the app it does not contain my latest changes.  It seems to install one of my previous builds.

Is the problem in:
- the way I create the apk?
- a cache on the phone that has not been cleared?

How do I get Eclispe to make a current apk, and how do I get my phone to install it?

How can I verify which version of my code is in a particular apk file?

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: maybe the downloaded APK is cached and your phone is never seeing the newest upload

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Eclipse isn't building the new .apk properly, though it sounds like you're exporting correctly. Are you giving the new .apk a different name from the old one? If not, then you could be downloading or installing the old one by accident.

You should be able to go into `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications` on your phone, then find your app and open its info page. The version string should be listed near the top, so you can verify that the latest version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try running "adb logcat | tee logfile" (or adb logcat > logfile) before you begin the install attempt, then ctrl-C it and go over the file with a fine tooth comb - there's likely some hints of the problem buried within the noise.